# Is there a way to notify the Browser that the current Language has changed?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In a SPA that is initially loaded with `<html lang="fr">` when the user changes the language to english, chrome for example still offers the user to translate the website from french to his OS Language eventhough the lang attribute has been updated with:

`document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'en');`

So I'm wondering if there is a anotherway to change the working language of the website, or to tell the browser that the current language of the website has changed.

Comment: You could maybe store the language in localStorage and do a browser reload.  You might need to make your HTML initially have no language set, and always set this in JS.   ps.  I've not tested this approach, but I've a feeling Chrome maybe locks the language on first seeing it, and changes later are maybe ignored.  Another option, seen as you have a language selector is maybe disable it -> `<html translate="no">`

Comment: if you don't hardcode the lang, i believe the lang info should be sent in subsequent http requests as accept-language header. would that help to identify the changes.